# How to merge new values only?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, arcgis-10.3

Using ArcGIS 10.3 Desktop.

We have a single feature class within our geodatabase which is a merge of all the other feature classes in the geodatabase.  I would like to build a model that we can run everytime we input new data which will automatically take ONLY the new data that hasn't yet been merged in the other feature classes (and ideally look for and replace any of the older data that has had an attribute changed) and merge those values with the existing "AllFeatures" feature class.

Is this possible?  What tool(s) would I use?

Comment: do you have the licence level for versioning ? I think this would be the best solution in your case if you can use it.

Comment: what is the type of feature in your FC

Comment: Well this is actually something we would want to do in our polygon gdb, line gdb and also the point gdb. I just said one to make it simpler for the question.  Each merge would be merging the same type of data only

And I think we have the highest license level...but we dont have any versioning going on right now.  That's in the plans for months or years down the line I think...

Answer (score 1):

I think that versioning is really what you need. An alternative way is to manually update a field value to know which are the new features

Without versioning, the solution depends on the type of feature.  :

- For points, you can run spatial join then select by attribute the points that are different in the old and new datasets (different attributes and/or distance value > threshold). Make then sure that you select by location the points of the "old" FC that do not touch the selected points of the old FC, then append the two layers (with the selection)
- For lines, you can use the "detect Feature Change" tool at first, then proceed like you did for the points.
- For polygons, use spatial join with "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO": features that are not identical will be new geometries, and checking the attribute table will tell you if some attributes have been changed.Then you can proceed like you did for the points.

Comment: We do have editor tracking enabled, so it shows date created and date last edited.  Would this be helpful?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I'm thinking maybe it would be OK if we did just delete the whole merged "AllFeatures" feature class each time and replaced it with a new merge - except, we would want to retain the values for the Transparency field if possible.  Do you think that would be easier to accomplish?

Comment: I think that there is no need to delete. You can select (by attributes) the features based on the date last edited, select (by location) all but those feature in the old database, then merge